# Remove recovery feature from recovery disk

Tags: macos, recovery

I mistakenly made a recovery disk from my USB external Hard drive. By making recovery dosk I can no longer use its entire 500 GB space. Now I want to restore this disk to original state so that I could use its entire space. How can I restore external HDD?

Comment: When you say "made a recovery disk", do you mean with the [Recovery Disk Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4848), or something else? Also, was there anything on the external drive that you care about (i.e. do we need to worry about data recovery, or just erase it and start over)?

Comment: Yes I made it with Recovery Disk Assistant and also there was data on the disk and want to recover it.